# How to Access one AWS Lambda from another Lambda located in a different template?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am using aws lambda, with AWS SAM. my SAM CLI version is 1.39.0. I have two template files. They are "template-outbound.yaml" and "template-user-related.yaml". In "template-outbound.yaml" I have a function called "SendEmailFunction". Below is its AWS SAM code.

```
SendEmailFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: SendEmailFunction
      CodeUri: xxx-restapi/
      Handler: source/email/send-email.sendEmail
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        SendEmailAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            Path: /email/send-email
            Method: post
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApiOutbound
```

In "template-user-related.yaml" I have a function called "LoginFunction". Below is its code.

```
LoginFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      FunctionName: LoginFunction
      CodeUri: xxx-restapi/
      Handler: source/user/login.login
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        LoginAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi 
          Properties:
            Path: /user/login
            Method: get
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi2
```

Below is my NodeJS code, accessing the "SendEmailFunction" from "LoginFunction".

```
try {

        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            region: 'us-east-1'
        });

        var params = {
            FunctionName: 'SendEmailFunction',
            InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
            LogType: 'Tail',
            Payload: JSON.stringify({
                "text": text            })
        };

        const result = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
        const response = JSON.parse(result.Payload);
        console.log(response);

        let fraudDetectedJson = {
            "statusCode": 400,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "error": "personal information detected"
            }),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        };

    } catch (error) {
        let errorJson = {
            "statusCode": 400,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "error": "error "
            }),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        };
        console.log(error);
        return errorJson;
    }
```

I need to execute "SendEmailFunction" from "LoginFunction". If both functions are in "template-outbound.yaml" I can execute this without issues, like below.

```
LoginFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      FunctionName: LoginFunction
      CodeUri: xxx-restapi/
      Handler: source/user/login.login
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        LoginAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi 
          Properties:
            Path: /user/login
            Method: get
            ApiId: !Ref AuthGatewayHttpApi2
      Policies: 
        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName:
              !Ref SendEmailFunction
      Environment:
        Variables:
          CREATE_EMAIL_MICROSERVICE_FUNCTION: !Ref SendEmailFunction
```

what changes i need to make in my template files to execute the function in "template-outbound.yaml" from the function in "template-user-related.yaml" ?

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda's name is not SendEmailFunction as you defined in the template file. It usually looks like `SendEmailFunction-<some_id>`. You should avoid hardcoding  the function's name/ARN by putting it to AWS SSM, then refer to that variable from "template-user-related.yaml" via intrinsic functions.

Define the SSM Parameter as follows:

```
  SendEmailFunctionName:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: "SOMETHING"
      Type: String
      Value: !Select [1, !Split ["/", !GetAtt SendEmailFunction.Arn]]
```

And in the other template you can refer to it using `!Sub`:

```
  Environment:
    Variables:
      CREATE_EMAIL_MICROSERVICE_FUNCTION:  !Sub "{{resolve:ssm:/SOMETHING}}"
```